# Setting a variable in JSP using a custom tag and passing it to a servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets

I have a custom tag like this `<user:current-location msg="!{#locationName}"/>` which works fine, but I want to assign it to a variable so I can pass the current location value to a servlet using a form.

I have tried setting the variable using `<c:set var = 'location_id' scope = 'session' value = '<user:current-location msg="!{#locationName}">'/>`

but when I do `<c:out value = '${location_id}'/>`, instead of printing out the name of the current location on the page, it just prints out  `<user:current-location msg="!{#locationName}">`  How can I get it to access what’s actually assigned to the variable?

If I can get that working, I would then like to do something like this in my form to be passed to the servlet in the post request `<input type="radio" name="locationName" value="${location_id}" checked="checked">`

I cannot use the old scriptlet syntax as this is deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this :

```
<c:set var = "location_id" scope ="session">
 <user:current-location msg="!{#locationName}"/>
</c:set>
```